# Removing Null records in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like below

```
Id value
1   \N
2   \N
3    a
4    b
5   \N
```

I want to remove the `\N` records, which are null, from the df. How to do this?

Comment: you can just `filter` them out. `filter(df.value != r'\N')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple `filter` should work.

```py
data_sdf.filter(data_sdf.value != r'\N').show()

# +---+-----+
# | id|value|
# +---+-----+
# |  3|    a|
# |  4|    b|
# +---+-----+
```

Comment: @NamithaJanardhanan - did you use the `r` before the quoted character? it shouldn;t give you the error if used correctly